# Matlab / Octave bwdist() in Python or C

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, numpy, scipy

Does anyone know of a Python replacement for Matlab / Octave bwdist() function? This function returns Euclidian distance of each cell to the closest non-zero cell for a given matrix. I saw an Octave C implementation, a pure Matlab implementation, and I was wondering if anyone had to implement this in ANSI C (which doesn't include any Matlab / Octave headers, so I can integrate from Python easily) or in pure Python.

Both links I mentioned are below:

[C++](http://octave-image.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.0.10/____bwdist_8cc-source.html)

[Matlab M-File](http://www.irit.fr/PERSONNEL/SAMOVA/joly/Teaching/M2IRR/IRR05/Barre-Piquot/bwdist.m)

As a test, a Matlab code / output looks something like this:

```
bw= [0   1   0   0   0;
     1   0   0   0   0;
     0   0   0   0   1;
     0   0   0   0   0;
     0   0   1   0   0]

D = bwdist(bw)

D =

   1.00000   0.00000   1.00000   2.00000   2.00000
   0.00000   1.00000   1.41421   1.41421   1.00000
   1.00000   1.41421   2.00000   1.00000   0.00000
   2.00000   1.41421   1.00000   1.41421   1.00000
   2.00000   1.00000   0.00000   1.00000   2.00000
```

I tested a recommended distance_transform_edt call in Python, which gave this result:

import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

```
a = np.array(([0,1,0,0,0],
              [1,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,0]))

res = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(a)
print res

[[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]]
```

This result does not seem to match the Octave / Matlab output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While Matlab `bwdist` returns distances to the closest non-zero cell, Python [`distance_transform_edt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html) returns distances “to the closest background element”. SciPy documentation is not clear about what it considers to be the “background”, there is some type conversion machinery behind it; in practice `0` is the background, non-zero is the foreground.

So if we have matrix `a`:

```
>>> a = np.array(([0,1,0,0,0],
              [1,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0,1],
              [0,0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,1,0,0]))
```

then to calculate the same result we need to replaces ones with zeros and zeros with ones, e.g. consider matrix `1-a`:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])
>>> 1 - a
array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]])
```

In this case [`scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html) gives the expected results:

```
>>> distance_transform_edt(1-a)
array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  2.        ,  2.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.41421356,  1.41421356,  1.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.41421356,  2.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 2.        ,  1.41421356,  1.        ,  1.41421356,  1.        ],
       [ 2.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  2.        ]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Does [`scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html) meet your needs?

Comment: per @jetxee's comment, I changed the code and this call works.

Answer (score 2):

No need to do the 1-a

```
>>> distance_transform_edt(a==0)
    array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  2.        ,  2.        ],
           [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  1.41421356,  1.41421356,  1.        ],
           [ 1.        ,  1.41421356,  2.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
           [ 2.        ,  1.41421356,  1.        ,  1.41421356,  1.        ],
           [ 2.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ,  2.        ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `distanceTransform()` from **OpenCV** that Calculates the distance to the closest zero pixel for each pixel of the source image.

Check this link: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#ga8a0b7fdfcb7a13dde018988ba3a43042

Comment: This answer is actually correct - usage:

`cv.distanceTransform( (255-image), cv.DIST_L2, cv.DIST_MASK_PRECISE)`