# How to efficiently calculate distance to nearest 1 in mask in numpy?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, scipy

In numpy I have a 2d array of 1s and 0s. I need to calculate a new array (same dimensions) where each element contains the distance to the nearest 1 from the corresponding point in the mask array.

e.g.

```
a=np.array(
[[1,1,0],
[1,0,0],
[1,0,0]])
```

I need b to look like this:

```
array([[0,0,1],
       [0,1,1.41],
       [0,1,2]])
```

PS. I'll be doing this over very large arrays, so the more efficient the better!
Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for the equivalent of MATLAB's [`bwdist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwdist.html) ; check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5260232/71131) for more details. The short answer is to use [`scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt.html#scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt).

Comment: Great -thanks! That works nicely. For completeness the code that worked was b=scipy.ndimage.morphology.distance_transform_edt(1-a)